# Skip hidden tab indexes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following html:

```
<span tabindex="19">

</span>

<span tabindex="20">

</span>

<span tabindex="21">

</span>

<span id="hidden" tabindex="22">

</span>

<span tabindex="23">

</span>

<span tabindex="24">

</span>
```

As you can see one of the span is hidden, the code to hide it is

```
#hidden
{
display: none;
}
```

I want a behavior where tab skips the hidden indexes. So i want something like this when i click tab:-
go to 19,20,21,23,24

I have no way of controlling the tab indexes as they are coming hard coded in the html i process.

Comment: it works fine. check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/pd7Ld85h/

Answer (score 3):

Thank you guys!!

I tried a lot of things, so i was wrong in hiding it using

```
#hidden
{
display : none.
}
```

I tried

```
#hidden
{visibility : hidden }
```

and tab skips the links which are marked as hidden.

Answer (score 1):

You could give it a negative tabindex which is supposed to be ignored by the browser. There are jQuery plugins that do this as well, such as SkipOnTab https://github.com/joelpurra/skipontab.

```
var $hidden = $('#hidden');
$hidden.attr('tabindex', '-' + $hidden.attr('tabindex'));
```

Answer (score 0):

It would help if you posted your code, but you could try something like this:

```
$("#hidden").attr("disabled","disabled");
```

Comment: or `$('#hidden').prop('disabled', true);`

Answer (score 0):

Normally the tab-event automatic skips a non visible HTML-element. However, the hard coded HTML part can override with JavaScript after the page has been loaded:

```
<script>
    window.addEventListener("load", function()
    {
        document.getElementById("hidden").setAttribute("tabindex", "-1");
    });
</script>
```

JQuery is also a solution, but 90kByte is a little bit heavy for this simply task.